# Three Screens: Duplicate primary screen and have 3rd secondary screen without launcher

Tags: 14.04, unity, multiple-monitors, launcher

I have two screens, that I use for working and surfing, the primary (with unity launcher) is 16:9 and the secondary (without unity launcher) 5:4. When I have guests or lie in my bed I would like to duplicate the primary screen on my big TV screen (16:9) to have the unity starter in sight. 
Right now I just can have all 3 screens showing the same or all three screens showing showing a different part of the workspace.
Is there a way to configure the screens like described?
Would be so comfortable :)

Comment: Oh, wait, you can only set the launcher on *all* screens, or one. If you duplicate the one without launcher, you won't (can't) have it on the duplicate as well. So no, that's not possible